# Is this c# return statement good/bad in terms of performance?

Tags: c#, string, return

My static method returns the following concatenated string like this

`return (Sb.ToString() + "  " + ds.Tables[1].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString() + "  " + ds.Tables[2].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());`

Is this a good/bad practise or should i use stringbuilder for it....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

String concatenation in a single shot will be faster than using a `StringBuilder` - although if `Sb` is already a `StringBuilder`, it *might* make sense to append to that instead (assuming it's a local variable). Assuming this is actually data which has come from a database, the time taken to fetch it is going to *vastly* exceed the string concatenation here anyway.

Note that you don't need all these calls to `ToString()` - this would do just as well:

```
return (Sb + " " + ds.Tables[1].Rows[0].ItemArray[0] + " " + 
        ds.Tables[2].Rows[0].ItemArray[0]);
```

Here's the equivalent using the existing builder:

```
return Sb.Append(" ")
         .Append(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0].ItemArray[0])
         .Append(" ")
         .Append(ds.Tables[2].Rows[0].ItemArray[0])
         .ToString();
```

This *might* be slightly faster - it will depend on various things. Personally I'd probably use the concatenation version anyway, as it's slightly simpler IMO. I highly doubt that you'd see much difference in performance. Note that this is a bit of a special case, as you've already got a `StringBuilder`; in the general case of concatenating a set of items where they can all be specified in one compile-time expression, concatenation can be faster as a single method call can provide all the required information.

I have a [page on `StringBuilder` vs string concatenation](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/stringbuilder.html) if you want more details and guidelines.

Comment: Will it really be faster? Might be "best practice" to use StringBuilder though, don't you think?

Comment: @Filip: Yes, it will be faster. It will result in a single call to `String.Concat` which can look at the lengths of *all* the strings involved, work out the exact size of buffer required, copy them all in, and you're done. No extra `StringBuilder` object required; no expanding buffer (potentially involving more reallocations). It's definitely *not* best practice to use `StringBuilder` without understanding why it's *sometimes* more efficient.

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur: In that case it *may* be faster to append to the existing `StringBuilder` and call `ToString` at the end. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is more readable:

```
return String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", 
                     Sb, 
                     ds.Tables[1].Rows[0].ItemArray[0],
                     ds.Tables[2].Rows[0].ItemArray[0]);
```

About concatenating strings or using StringBuilder:

[Concatenating Strings Efficiently](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html)
[StringBuilder and String Concatenation](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/StringBuilderComp11232005235258PM/StringBuilderComp.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you're calling this in a tight loop, you'll be probably be better off using `StringBuilder` (but this piece should be profiled nevertheless). Otherwise, concatenation is perfectly fine. I would change it, however, to `String.Format()` for maintainability/readability reasons.

Comment: Even if you're calling it in a loop, a `StringBuilder` isn't going to help - notice that this is a *return* statement... the result of the concatenation is going to be returned immediately. `StringBuilder` will almost certainly be *slower* (to an almost irrelevant extent, probably) than using concatenation here.